# How do I print out System.Min_Int in Ada?

Tags: ada

With GNAT, I'm trying to print out `System.Min_Int`

```
Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Put(System.Min_Int);
```

Yields this:

> "warning: value not in range of type "Ada.Text_Io.Integer_Io.Num" "

I also tried

> Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Put_Line(Integer'Image(System.Min_Int));

Which yields:

> value not in range of type "Standard.Integer"

How can I print `System.Min_Int` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Confusingly, `System.Min_Int` in at least one recent Gnat, appears to be a `Long_Integer` (though as Simon points out, it is actually Long_Long_Integer, and on some compilers but not all, these have the same range).

So, the following works (in gcc4.9.3):
`Put_Line(Long_Integer'Image(System.Min_Int));`
reporting `-9223372036854775808`.

And so does `Ada.Long_Integer_Text_IO.Put(System.Min_Int);`

On the other hand, you may have been trying to find the minimum value of the `Integer` type, which is ...`Integer'First`, and sure enough,

`Put_Line(Integer'Image(Integer'First));`
reports -2147483648

The rationale for the difference is that Ada can support an uncountable number of integer types, but provides a few default ones like `Integer` for convenience.

`System.Min_Int` and friends reflect the limits of your specific system : attempting to declare larger integer types is legal, but will not compile on your system (i.e. until you upgrade the compiler).

In normal use, you will either use Integer or better, integer typ4es you declare with ranges appropriate to your problem. And the limits of each such type obviously can't be built into the language or even the `System` package. Instead, you use the predefined attributes, such as `'First` and `'Last` to query the relevant integer type.

So you can explore your machine's limits with the following:

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with System;

procedure pmin is
   type Big_Integer is range System.Min_Int ..System.Max_Int;
   package Big_Integer_IO is new Integer_IO(Num => Big_Integer);
begin
   Big_Integer_IO.Put(System.Min_Int);
   Put(" to ");
   Big_Integer_IO.Put(System.Max_Int);
   New_Line;
end pmin;
```

Here (gcc4.9.3) I get the result:

> -9223372036854775808 to  9223372036854775807

If System.Min_Int is no longer in the range of Long_Integer in Gnat/gcc 6.1 I'm curious to see what this does on your system. Please add your test result in a comment.

Comment: `Put_Line(Long_Integer'Image(System.Min_Int));`gives me `value not in range of type "Standard.Long_Integer"` (this is with gcc-gnat-6.1 on i686.

Comment: See expanded answer. It worked on gcc4.9.3, but presumably the `System` limits have been expanded. Find "System.ads" on your machine if you want to check. Or declare an integer type : `type Big_Integer is  range System.Min ..System.Max;` and instantiate the generic integer I/O package with that type. I'll update the answer in a few...

Comment: Ok, it's a Long_Long_Integer on my system, so Long_Long_Integer'Image would do.

Comment: Oh jeez... hence "in at least one recent Gnat" in my answer. I'm guessing gcc as a whole is moving to full 128 bit integer support. Well this is why the system limits and the definitions of the inbuilt types are divorced from each other.

Comment: @brian, which recent GNAT? it’s `Long_Long_Integer` at 64 bits on Intel Mac (x86_64-apple-darwin) since GCC 4.7.0 at least, and arm-eabi looks the same. However, `Long_Integer` is 64 bits on Mac, 32 bits on arm-eabi. If you compile with -gnatS you get a listing of (something like) `package Standard`.

Comment: @SimonWright : I stand corrected, according to System.ads it is Long_Long_Integer.  My error arose because on these targets, Long_Integer and Long_Long_Integer have the same range ( hence I wrote  "appears to be" rather than "is ") while presumably gnat6.1 has embraced 128-bit Long_Long_Integer.

Comment: No, it's a *universal_integer*. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38256741/827263). I should have read your answer more closely before posting mine; I now see you already demonstrated using `type Big_Integer is range System.Min_Int ..System.Max_Int;`.

Comment: Yes, strictly it is a Universal_Integer like all named constants. But its declaration (in system.ads) is something like `Min_Int : constant := Long_Long_Integer'First;`

Comment: A named number can be initialized with a constant of type `Long_Long_Integer`, but it inherits only the value of the constant, not its type. `Long_Long_Integer'First` is used only for convenience. Try evaluating `Min_Int'Size` and see what happens.

Answer (score 4):

`System.Min_Int` and `System.Max_Int` are *named numbers*. Logically they are of type *universal_integer*. They can be implicitly converted to an integer type (just like integer constants like `42`), but of course the type needs to be big enough to hold it.

There is no predefined integer type that's guaranteed to be able to hold the values of `System.Min_Int` and `System.Max_Int`. An implementation isn't even required to define `Long_Integer`, and `Integer` is only required to be at least 16 bits.

Fortunately it's easy to define your own integer type with the necessary range.

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
with System;
procedure Min_Max is
    type Max_Integer is range System.Min_Int .. System.Max_Int;
begin
    Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("System.Min_Int = " & Max_Integer'Image(System.Min_Int));
    Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("System.Max_Int = " & Max_Integer'Image(System.Max_Int));
end Min_Max;
```

The output on my system:

```
System.Min_Int = -9223372036854775808
System.Max_Int =  9223372036854775807
```